# Print spec reporter output to file in WebdriverIO?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm trying to find a way to print spec reporter output to a text file once the test suite is complete. I'm using WebdriverIO but none of the completion callbacks seem to provide any access to the actual report output. There's also no documentation on any config variable you can pass in to set a file output. There an `outputDir` option but it only writes the log before the actual report to the selected location.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use `tee` to write all output of the test suite to a file and stdout. The report is then contained at the end of the file.

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js | tee test-report.txt
```

For running individual tests run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js -- --spec <Spec File Name> | tee test-report.txt
```